# Decode some of these characters

Tags: php, imap

I am trying to fetch some html template emails via PHP IMAP in which email is fetched quite fine except some characters that keep displaying like:

1. Â
2. â
3. â€“

Answer (score 0):

Imap encoding is really hard to handle.
One solution is [force_utf-8](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8)

This can solve most of encoding issues

Comment: that helped for the 2nd and 3rd but 1st is still bugging

Comment: add this 'header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');'